# Creating a superscript in mtext

Tags: r

I have the following dataframe

```
Data1 <- data.frame(pH = c(8,8.5,6,7.1,9), EC50 = c(20,11,5,25,50))
Data2 <- data.frame(pH = c(7,7.2,6.5,8.2,8.5), EC50 = c(13,15,18,25,19))
```

Using `par` I create two graphs on one plot:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1), oma=c(3,3,1,1), mar=c(2,2,3,1), cex.axis=1.3)
plot(x=Data1[,'pH'], y=Data1[,'EC50'])
plot(x=Data2[,'pH'], y=Data2[,'EC50'])
```

Because I used `par`, I cannot specify the `xlab` and `ylab` in `plot`,
therefore I use `mtext`.
I would like to write a superscript in my `ylab`, however, I do not know how to do so,
when using `mtext`.

I have tried the following

```
mtext(expression("Cu^{2+} at EC50"), side=2, line = 4, padj=1, at=30, cex=1.2)
```

but can't seem to get the `2+` as a superscript above the Cu.

Any help is more than welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to build your expression within the `expression` call. See the examples at [Mathematical Annotation in R](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/grDevices/html/plotmath.html).

In your case I found

```
mtext(expression(paste( plain("Cu") ^ plain("2+"), plain(" at EC50") )), side=2, line = 4, padj=1, at=30, cex=1.2)
```

gave a reasonable result

Answer (score 5):

```
mtext(expression(paste("Cu"^"2+","at EC50",sep="")))
```