# Superscript in figure caption line spacing

Tags: r, text, superscript

Please forgive me for not being able to properly ask questions on this forum.  I am very new to R and am trying to absorb as much as i can.  I originally started this page with a question about how to create a super script character in a 5-line figure caption.  I have figured out my original problem of not being able to use:

```
mtext(expression(paste(plain("begining of figure caption") ^ plain("superscript 
characters"), plain("end of figure caption"))), line=5.5, cex=0.7, adj=0, side=1)
```

with with a multi-lined caption. Apparently the carriage return+line feed will throw off the

```
mtext(expression(paste
```

expression.  Now that i know mtext only works for one line of text (got mixed up with AutoCAD mtext)  my new code looks like:

```
mtext('first line of caption', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line =1.5, cex= 0.70, adj = 0) 
mtext('second line of caption', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line =2.5, cex= 0.70, adj = 0)
mtext('third line of caption', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line =3.5, cex= 0.70, adj = 0)
mtext(expression(paste(plain("begining of third line figure caption") ^ plain("superscript characters"), plain("end of third line of figure caption"))), line=4.5, cex=0.7, adj=0, side=1)
mtext('fifth line of caption', side = 1, outer = TRUE, line =5.5, cex= 0.70, adj = 0)
```

The above code prints the lines in the correct order and with super script characters(small victory).  But now my issue is that the lines are not equally spaced.  The forth line is closer to the third and the fifth line appears to be floating below the fourth line.

Comment: Similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17743351/creating-a-superscript-in-mtext

Comment: I tried to apply the posted solution but still cant seem to get it to work.  Please review the original post again.  Thanks

Comment: start with a very short caption, and build up from there.

Comment: ...and it'd probably be much better to use knitr to do something like this. That way your captions go in the tex, and you generate the figures with the minimum content required.

Comment: you should produce a minimal executable example that reproduces the problem. In particular, I'd guess that 4 to 5 lines of text are completely irrelevant and the problem would still occur with 4 to 5 characters of text.

Comment: I think I am getting closer to figuring out what my problem is.  I think the problem is i am using <cr><lf> to make the mtext appear on multiple lines. I am now investigating using 5 mtext commands instead of one for all five lines

Comment: @TooTone  I guess the 4 to 5 lines of text was relevent to my question

Comment: @dubbbdan cool, it's not uncommon to find the answer in the process of refining your problem down to its minimal characteristics. It's good practise to submit (and accept) an answer to your own question when you discover it this way, if you can.